R - Correct datatype but date is "NA"
Updated: 7/6 10:45am pdt
The data is loaded via combining two files. Here are the specific steps I used.
    cdf <- list.files(path = '/cloud/project/cap1/Capstone-dnb, pattern = '\\.csv$',  full.names = TRUE)

    list_of_dfs <- lapply(cdf, read.csv)

    combined_df <- do.call(rbind, list_of_dfs)

    str(combined_df)


Here is the output of dput(head(cdf))

> dput(head(cdf))
structure(list(ride_id = c("1068AB1B8F12FE23", "4DE50A4FC7687A0D", 
"1C78B5F337CBFC93", "D231CE7990A3AA52", "2.30E+15", "EB21BB139ABF6174"
), rideable_type = c("docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", 
"docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike"), started_at = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), ended_at = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), start_station_name = c("Sheffield Ave & Wellington Ave", 
"Daley Center Plaza", "Sheridan Rd & Irving Park Rd", "Delano Ct & Roosevelt Rd", 
"Clark St & Leland Ave", "Clark St & Leland Ave"), start_station_id = c(115, 
81, 240, 626, 326, 326), end_station_name = c("Ashland Ave & Belle Plaine Ave", 
"Dearborn St & Van Buren St", "Broadway & Sheridan Rd", "Wabash Ave & Roosevelt Rd", 
"Southport Ave & Irving Park Rd", "Clark St & Bryn Mawr Ave"), 
    end_station_id = c(246, 624, 256, 59, 318, 460), start_lat = c(41.9363, 
    41.8842, 41.9542, 41.8675, 41.9671, 41.9671), start_lng = c(-87.6527, 
    -87.6296, -87.6544, -87.6322, -87.6674, -87.6674), end_lat = c(41.9561, 
    41.8763, 41.9528, 41.8672, 41.9542, 41.9836), end_lng = c(-87.6688, 
    -87.6292, -87.65, -87.626, -87.6644, -87.6692), member_casual = c("casual", 
    "member", "member", "member", "member", "member"), ride_length = structure(c(46800, 
    14400, 7200, 7200, 25200, 28800), class = c("hms", "difftime"
    ), units = "secs"), day_of_week = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> 

Updated: 7/6 8:50
Thanks for the questions!
Re: Code... The following two statements were both tried independently.  These correctly set the datatype according to print(cdf). But according to spec(cdf) the datatypes are incorrect.
    cdf$started_at <- col_datetime(cdf$started_at, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

    cdf$started_at <- as.POSIXct(cdf$started_at, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

This is a screen capture of the data.

![Example of data][1]


Appreciate any help on this. I have a column of dates formatted as %m/%d/%y %H:%M. The column datatype is col_datetime.  When I view the dataset, the datatype is correct however the date values are all NA. I've checked the format of the date versus the format I specified many times and it looks fine. [Correct datatype, but no data.]

Code in question: started_at = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
Input: 6/3/20 11:20 as a string
Output: "NA" date value,  column datatype set correctly.  See image


Verified the argument of col_datetime precisely matches that of the data.
Tried using `as.POSIXct` instead of `col_date_time`.

Tried using Date.

Validated source data could be formatted as desired. To verify no hidden characters came with the data.


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/wjvFD5UY.png


Can you please add the code you've tried? That way it's easier to see where your approach fails.

lubridate::mdy_hm("6/3/20 11:20") may work for you, but like Andre said, it is easier to see what issue you are having if you provide a reproducible example

This will help us help you: Please run dput(head(YOUR_DATA_FRAME)) and edit your question to include the output. That will create a code "recipe" so that we can verify potential solutions using an exact replica of your data, with the same formatting and structure. When you include a screenshot, we can only guess at the format and structure underneath what is displayed. (And we'd have to retype it in ourselves to try out solutions, which is a waste of time when you could just include it.)

Ok, so it looks like the problem step is where you load in the data. The column type is mis-specified so the correct data never makes it into R. How are you loading the data?

col_datetime is meant to be called within the col parameter of a read_* function from readr. For example, read_csv(file_name, cols = cols(started_at = col_datetime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M")))

Completely agree.  I should have included the cols definitions I started with allong with the csv statment. Which is essentially identical to yours.   Here are the definitions.                                           column_types <- cols(
ride_id = col_character(),
rideable_type = col_character(),
started_at = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"),
ended_at = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"),
start_station_name = col_character(),
start_station_id = col_character(),
end_station_name = col_character(),
end_station_id = col_character() )

Thanks for adding the data sample and the code you used to import the data. One thing I'm confused about is that cdf looks like it would be a vector of files in your first line of code, then you make combined_df which should read those files and combine them, but then you perhaps assign that back to cdf? (because the cdf you refer to otherwise is a data.frame.) Are the datetime columns already NA in combined_df? I wonder if readr::read_csv might do any better with your particular data than read.csv?

Thanks for the question.  cdf and combined_df are equivalent. Got tired of typing the extra characters. Also, re: NA, yes the datetime columns were NA in combined_df.  However, I checked the original, cleaned files and NA did not exist anywhere. So something I did in R must hsve changed them to NA.  The majority of which was experimenting with datatypes. Unfortunately that is no longer in history.
